# How to Install Viber on Ubuntu 13.10, 32bit

Tags: software-installation

I hope everyone is OK

I would like to know if someone knows how to install Viber on Ubuntu 13.10, 32 Bit.

Best Regards,

Comment: Why is this marked duplicate? It clearly asks for a "32 bit" installation. The supposedly duplicate answer only refers to 64 bit. (And the answer below is a clever trick to do so).

Answer (score 9):

Viber is still in beta release for linux and runs only on 64-bit systems. To install viber's stable release for windows, you need wine. To install, open a terminal(using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and then type:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
wget http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/windows/ViberSetup.exe
wine ViberSetup.exe
```

<sub>Source:</sub>

- [Question on installing via wine on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718626/how-to-install-viber-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

As Jobin stated in his answer Viber for Linux is still in Beta.  In order to install it, you have to be running the 64bit version of Ubuntu and not the 32bit.

If you do want to keep the 32bit, use the option in Jobin's answer.  If you decide to go with 64bit Ubuntu, still keep in mind that Viber is still in Beta.

To install Viber Beta on 64 bit Ubuntu only, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
wget -c download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/Viber.zip
unzip Viber.zip
cd Viber
./Viber.sh
```

<sup>*Source:* [LinuxG](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-the-viber-im-client-on-the-most-popular-64-bit-only-linux-systems/)</sup>