# Mysql workbench installation failed?

Tags: package-management, mysql, dependencies

I am unable to install mysql workbench community addition on ubuntu 14.04
I am installing latest version by debian file downloaded from server

```
1. sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
2. sudo gdebi mysql-workbench-community-6.3.3-1ubu1404-amd64.deb
```

I get following error and it stopped

```
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-workbench-community
```

when I run this command

```
#sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get this

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 or
                                            libgl1:amd64
                                   Depends: python-paramiko:amd64 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I tried following

```
 sudo apt-get -f install
```

and again no luck

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gcc-4.8-base:amd64 libasn1-8-heimdal:amd64 libatk1.0-0:amd64
  libatkmm-1.6-1:amd64 libavahi-client3:amd64 libavahi-common-data:amd64
  libavahi-common3:amd64 libbaloocore4 libbaloofiles4 libbalooxapian4
  libcairo2:amd64 libcairomm-1.0-1:amd64 libctemplate2:amd64 libcups2:amd64
  libcurl3:amd64 libdatrie1:amd64 libdrm-intel1:amd64 libdrm-nouveau2:amd64
  libdrm-radeon1:amd64 libelf1:amd64 libexpat1:amd64 libffi6:amd64
  libfontconfig1:amd64 libfreetype6:amd64 libgcrypt11:amd64
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64
  libglapi-mesa:amd64 libglib2.0-0:amd64 libglibmm-2.4-1c2a:amd64
  libgmp10:amd64 libgnome-keyring0:amd64 libgnutls-deb0-28:amd64
  libgnutls26:amd64 libgpg-error0:amd64 libgraphite2-3:amd64
  libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 libgssapi3-heimdal:amd64 libgtk2.0-0:amd64
  libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a:amd64 libharfbuzz0b:amd64 libhcrypto4-heimdal:amd64
  libheimbase1-heimdal:amd64 libheimntlm0-heimdal:amd64 libhogweed2:amd64
  libhx509-5-heimdal:amd64 libidn11:amd64 libjasper1:amd64 libjbig0:amd64
  libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 libjpeg8:amd64 libk5crypto3:amd64 libkeyutils1:amd64
  libkidletime4 libkrb5-26-heimdal:amd64 libkrb5-3:amd64 libkrb5support0:amd64
  libldap-2.4-2:amd64 libllvm3.4:amd64 libnepomukcleaner4 libnettle4:amd64
  libp11-kit0:amd64 libpango-1.0-0:amd64 libpangocairo-1.0-0:amd64
  libpangoft2-1.0-0:amd64 libpangomm-1.4-1:amd64 libpciaccess0:amd64
  libpcrecpp0:amd64 libpixman-1-0:amd64 libpoppler-qt4-4 libpython2.7:amd64
  libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 libqjson0
  libqmobipocket1 libreadline6:amd64 libroken18-heimdal:amd64 librtmp1:amd64
  libsasl2-2:amd64 libsasl2-modules:amd64 libsasl2-modules-db:amd64
  libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:amd64 libsqlite3-0:amd64 libssl1.0.0:amd64
  libstdc++6:amd64 libtasn1-6:amd64 libthai0:amd64 libtiff5:amd64
  libtinyxml2.6.2:amd64 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:amd64 libwind0-heimdal:amd64
  libx11-6:amd64 libx11-xcb1:amd64 libxau6:amd64 libxcb-dri2-0:amd64
  libxcb-dri3-0:amd64 libxcb-glx0:amd64 libxcb-present0:amd64
  libxcb-render0:amd64 libxcb-shm0:amd64 libxcb-sync1:amd64 libxcb1:amd64
  libxcomposite1:amd64 libxcursor1:amd64 libxdamage1:amd64 libxdmcp6:amd64
  libxext6:amd64 libxfixes3:amd64 libxi6:amd64 libxinerama1:amd64
  libxml2:amd64 libxrandr2:amd64 libxrender1:amd64 libxshmfence1:amd64
  libxxf86vm1:amd64 libzip2:amd64
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-workbench-community:amd64
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 135 MB disk space will be freed.
```

Comment: what is the result of `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: let me try that sir. is it safe?

Comment: yes it's safe try it

Comment: no luck pasted reponse in question

Comment: what is the output of `uname -a`

Comment: Linux americostechadmin-phpserver 3.13.0-53-generic #89-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 20 10:34:28 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: I think i am not admin(root user). so i try by login as admin ?

Comment: I'm writting an answer or your wait me a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Linux americostechadmin-phpserver 3.13.0-53-generic #89-Ubuntu SMP Wed
>   May 20 10:34:28 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

This shows that your system is 32 bit `i686` instead you are installing 64bit package, so this raises that errors.

To solve that run the command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

press `y` , this would remove the package you are going to install.

Now you have to install the 32 bit version not the 64 bit.

In order to learn how to install 64bit on 32bit machine please read this [How to install 64-bit .deb file on a 32-bit machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513260/how-to-install-64-bit-deb-file-on-a-32-bit-machine)

you can install from repositoy  using the comamnd

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

Comment: okay how to get 32 bit version. let me try that

Comment: how can i get deb for 32 bit?

Comment: you dont have to get 32bit deb, you can install it from repository. check my answer again

Comment: I did sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench yesterday but that does not open mysql workbench  after installation. clicking n number of times and no result. let me try one more time

Comment: ok try it and give me results

Comment: same again no success. it  doest open workbench while it successfully installed and showing under menu tab "programming"

Comment: from command line what is the output of command `mysql-workbench`

Comment: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Glib::FileError'
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: This is another problem than mysql-workbench, your package is installed correctly, so you should search for this error. It's better to ask it as another question to get  more help, and I'm trying to search for this problem

Comment: also sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench gives very old version not latest

Comment: let ask another question

Comment: It gives you the version found in the Ubuntu reposiroty

Comment: I think I need to ask tomorrow doesn’t allow me to ask another questions may be due to limit or something else

Comment: Ah ok, anyway i'm searching for this problem, if i found some solution i'll send it to you